# RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, kernel, configure

I am trying to create network and to add hosts with mininet but I got the error:

```
sudo mn
[sudo] password for udooer:
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2
*** Adding switches:
s1
*** Adding links:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Caught exception. Cleaning up...

Exception: Error creating interface pair (h1-eth0,s1-eth1): RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

I think something is missing in the kernel configuration. Which parameters am I supposed to activate?

Here is my corresponding .config file part

```
#
# Core Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=m
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_ACCT is not set
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK is not set
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROCFS=y
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMEOUT is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMESTAMP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_DCCP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_SCTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_UDPLITE is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_AMANDA is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_H323 is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IRC is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_NETBIOS_NS is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SNMP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PPTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SANE is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SIP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK_TIMEOUT is not set
CONFIG_NF_NAT=m
CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED=y
# CONFIG_NF_NAT_AMANDA is not set
# CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_NAT_IRC is not set
# CONFIG_NF_NAT_SIP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y

#
# IP: Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=m
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_AH is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ECN is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_RPFILTER is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TTL is not set
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REJECT=m
# CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_SYNPROXY is not set
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ULOG=m
CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_NETMAP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT=m
# CONFIG_NF_NAT_PPTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_NAT_H323 is not set
CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE=m
# CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_CLUSTERIP is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ECN is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TTL is not set
CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPTABLES=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPFILTER=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARP_MANGLE=m
```